# Load Applet via Javascript function on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, applet

I am trying to load an applet on demand via javascript.

Here is what I've tried:

```
function startApplet() {
    document.write('<applet code="com.pwc.envoyapp.applet.SampleApplet" height=30 width=40 archive="ucfapplet.jar"></applet>');
}
```

The problem is that it loads the applet in a new page. I need it to open it on the same page so that session keys generated by the applet are preserved.

Is there a way to get the applet to load on the same page?

Comment: I presume you have already rejected [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) because that script writes directly to the page, ruling it out for 'on demand'.  It is a major (& irritating) failing of an otherwise good script.  :(

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like:

```
document.getElementById("appletContainer").innerHTML = "<applet ... />";
```

of course you'd need the element to exist so somewhere in your DOM you'd have:

```
<div id="appletContainer"></div>
```

as an empty element waiting to be populated.